# Decoding enum in Swift 5 - This CANNOT be this hard

Tags: swift, swift5, codable, decodable, encodable

I've been trying for the past 3-4 hours to get this stupid thing to decode this enum correctly and now am incredibly frustrated with this! I have a `json` string returning from an API that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "contractType": 0
  }
]
```

I am trying to map THAT to an enum called `ContractType`. This is my whole `ContractType` enum

```
enum ContractType: Int {
    case scavenger = 0
}
```

and this is my extension I tried to make it conform to the `Codable` protocol.

```
extension ContractType: Codable {
    enum Key: Int, CodingKey {
        case rawValue
    }

    enum CodingError: Error {
        case unknownValue
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Key.self)
        let rawValue = try? container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .rawValue)

        switch rawValue {
        case 0:
            self = .scavenger
        default:
            throw CodingError.unknownValue
        }
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: Key.self)
        switch self {
        case .scavenger:
            try container.encode(0, forKey: .rawValue)
        }
    }
}
```

What the heck am I doing wrong!? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This all you need here.

```
struct Contract: Codable {
    var contractType: ContractType

    enum ContractType: Int, Codable {
        case scavenger
    }
}

do {
    let contract = try JSONDecoder().decode([Contract].self, from: json)
    print(contract.contractType)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer man. I ended up using this implementation even though it's basically the same as PGDev's answer above. I really appreciate it.

Comment: always happy to help.

Answer (score 3):

To parse the above *JSON response*, `Codable` models should be,

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let contractType: ContractType
}

enum ContractType: Int, Codable {
    case scavenger = 0
}
```

Now, parse the *JSON* `data` like so,

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode([Response].self, from: data)
    print(response)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

There is no need to explicitly implement `init(from:)` and `encode(to:)`. It will be handled by the compiler automatically.

Comment: I appreciate the quick response, your answer and Frankenstein's answer (below) are BOTH the correct answers! Thanks again! I was able to get this to work and it turns out it really ISN'T as hard as I was trying to make it! lol